# How do I change the directory my silly-code.cabal project looks for a parent cabal.project file in?

Tags: haskell, cabal, nix

I'm in a monorepo containing projects of many different languages. At the root of it, we want to have this:

```
└── haskell
    ├── cabal.project
    ├── one-lib
    │   ├── one-lib.cabal
    │   └── src
    │       └── OneLib.hs
    └── two-lib
        ├── two-lib.cabal
        └── src
            └── TwoLib.hs
```

and then from within other directories, like inside `some/nested-path` I want to have a `silly-code.cabal` that looks like

```
name: silly-code
build-type: Simple

-- Imaginary option
cabal.project-root-folder: ../../haskell/

library
  hs-source-dirs:
    src
  main-is:
    Main.hs
  build-depends:
    , one-lib   -- listed in ../../haskell/cabal.project
    , base < 5
```

is this possible?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you'd like to have a Haskell project outside of the `haskell`-language subtree of your repo?

Comment: Nixpkgs Haskell infrastructure doesn't know or care about cabal project files. Instead, you `haskellPackages.extend myPackages` to insert your own packages as an overlay. The `silly-code` can then have a `shell.nix` that references your extended Haskell package set to create a "Haskell installation" with the dependencies pre-installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, but not from your `.cabal` file. It must be specified on the `cabal` command-line, using the [`--project-file`](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.4/cabal-project.html#cmdoption-0) command-line flag.